# Using a regular expression for a choice of a few strings

Tags: regex, bash, command-line

This is the regular expression `'^(v{1,2})?(l|d)?\s+((\bblue\b)|(\bred\b)|(\bgrey\b))'`

It seems I can't get the formatting of the \s+ followed by the words which can go in the \s+

I want if to accept anything from the following strings 'vvlblue, vlblue, lblue, blue, dblue, vdblue, vvdblue, vvlred, vlred .... vdred, vvdred, vvlgrey, vlgrey ... vdgrey, vvdgrey)

If I enter

```
lblue
lred
dred
```

into stdin when running this I would like it to print

```
C - Colours: lblue
C - Colours: lblue, lred
C - Colours: lblue, lred, dred
```

.

It comes from this section of code

```
read -p ""
while [ $REPLY != "n" ]
do
        #^(v{1,2})?(l|d)?
        if [[ $REPLY =~ '^(v{1,2})?(l|d)?\s+((\bblue\b)|(\bred\b)|(\bgrey\b))' ]]
        then
                colours+=($REPLY)
                echo "C - Colours: "
                printf '%s,' "$colours[-]"
                printf "\n"
        else
                printf "Invalid colour\n"
        fi
        read -p ""
done
```

Even when I strip the line down to just

```
if [[ $REPLY =~ '^\s+(blue)' ]]
```

or I change it to

```
if [[ $REPLY =~ '^\s+(\bblue\b)' ]]
```

and enter the word blue, I still get "Invalid colour" as output

Comment: State your requirement clearly. What is that you are trying to do along with a minimal verifiable input and expected output.

Comment: @Inian is it better now? I edited it so it has the exact output that should print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code with some modification in the regex and the ouput:

```
colours=()
read -p ""
while [ $REPLY != "n" ]
        do

        if [[ $REPLY =~ ^(v{,2})(l|d)?(blue|red|grey)$ ]]
        then
                colours+=($REPLY)
                echo -n "C - Colours: "
                printf '%s, ' "${colours[@]}"
                printf "\n"
        else
                printf "Invalid colour\n"
                fi
                read -p ""
        done
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you only looking for red blue and grey? If so why don't you just do `red|blue|grey` for your regex? But here is the modified version, you don't need quotes for string regex comparison.

```sh
while read REPLY
do
        if [[ "$REPLY" =~ ^(v{1,2})?(l|d)?(blue|red|grey) ]]
        then
                colours="$colours $REPLY"
                echo "C - Colours: $colours"
        else
                printf "Invalid colour\n"
        fi
done
```

This is the output:

```
lblue
C - Colours:  lblue
lred
C - Colours:  lblue lred
dred
C - Colours:  lblue lred dred
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `v{1,2})?` eq `v{,2}`